# On trying to upload Chrome Extension screen shot always receiving Invalid size error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

On trying to upload chrome extension(Mandatory field) screen shot always getting error as image size is invalid.
I have provided the image size as 5kb,10kb,15kb,20kb,30,kb was still getting the image size invalid. 
Image size specifications are not mentioned anywhere Please provide the Image size specifications.

Please find the below screen shot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: The "size" refers to pixel dimensions, not to kilobytes.

Answer (score 2):

As per comment: the size here implies exact pixel size of the image.